# How to get photo of user json formatting view

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

I'm trying to get a photo to show on my view. Tried the below but it won't work:

```
  "attributes": {
              "src": "='https://aaa.sharepoint.com/sites/XXX/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=S&accountname=' + [$Email]",
              "title": "[$Display_x0020_Name]"
            }
```

The Email field is an email address. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you add "Email" column to your list view? Add Email column to list view & try using: `"src": "='/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=S&accountname=' + [$Email]",`. Make sure you are using correct **internal name** of Email column.

Comment: I eventually realised that (adding the field to the list view) Thanks

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON code seems good to me. Please make sure below things:

1. You added "Email" column to your list view - This is required to reference "Email" in JSON formatting.
2. You are using correct **internal name** of email column in JSON (`[$InternalNameOfColumn]`). You can get the exact internal name of your email column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Documentation**: [Use view formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting)